# Game Maker - Turn On/Off Sound

Tags: button, audio, game-maker

**What I have**

I have two rooms: `rm_home` and `rm_options`. I have a sound: `snd_Bgm`. And, I have three objects: `obj_bgm`, `obj_BtnOnClicked`, and `obj_BtnOffClicked`.

**What I want is very simple**

Player can turn on/off the `snd_Bgm`.

**What I have done**

In `obj_bgm`, I have these events:

> Create Event: set var `global.sound to 1`
>
> Room Start: stop sound `snd_Bgm`; if `global.sound == 1` then play sound `snd_Bgm`

In `obj_BtnOnClicked`, I have these events:

> Left-Pressed Event: play sound `snd_Bgm`; set var `global.sound to 1`

In `obj_BtnOffClicked`, I have these events:

> Left-Pressed Event: stop sound `snd_Bgm`; set var `global.sound to 0`

I put `obj_BtnOnClicked`, and `obj_BtnOffClicked` in `rm_options`, which can be accessed from `rm_home`. Then, I put `obj_bgm` in `rm_home`.

**This is the problem**

When game start, it will show `rm_home` and plays the `snd_bgm`. I go to `rm_options`, then click the `obj_BtnOffClicked` to turn off the sound, so the sound is off. But, when I go back to `rm_home`, the sound is on again.

**What I think**

I shouldn't put `Create Event: set var global.sound to 1` in `obj_bgm`, because when `rm_home` start, it takes the value of var `global.sound` from *Create Event*. But, if I put *Create Event* in `obj_BtnOnClicked` or `obj_BtnOffClicked`, it shows a *Get Error*.

What should I do? Please explain your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your rooms and your variables persistent ?

If rm_home is not persistent, it will restart every time you leave it. So every object placed in that room will be reset, including obj_bgm, which sets your sound variable to 1. I think this is the reason the sound restarts when you come back to rm_home.

If you still want to reset the room but not this particular object, you can make it persistent. You can do it either by ticking the box in the object or through code.

If you put the create event in a button object, it will not be read until you go to the options room. So when the obj_bgm tries to set it to 1, it does not exist yet. I believe it causes the error.

I make these remarks on assumptions, but I would need to see your code or your error message to help you further.

Comment: No, it wasn't persistent. So, as you said, I check the persistent option in `obj_bgm`, and it works! I don't know about persistent object before. Thanks